# Restricting the user to enter only numeric numeric number and float using angualrJS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how to restrict the user to enter only numeric digits and float values using angularJS. Let's say,

I want to allow the user to enter only 1234 or 1234.54 in some required fields. So, in this case i want to restrict the user to enter like -1234 or special characters or characters or - or entering only 0.

Please help me to know about this concept using angularJS

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="form.number" id="number" required>
```

**Number** restricts the input to numeric values, **step** restricts the amount of decimal places etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish that with the directive ng-required together with ng-pattern and a regular expression that catches your needs:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="regexThatMatchesWhatYouWant" ng-required="true" />
```

Comment: Can you tell me that regEx to use within the ng-pattern

Comment: @DIVA first decide what regex you want and later maybe i can help, but " 1234 or 1234.54... i want to restrict the user to enter like -1234 or special characters or characters or - or entering only 0." is too vague, and you have the answer

Comment: I want to allow the user to enter these both inputs 1234 or 1234.54